# MVC4 template not showing in Visual studio 2010, though MVC4 is installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, installation

[image] [image]

I have visual studio 2010 ultimate and MVC frameworks installed however when I open Visual studio it doesn't shows me new MVC templates, I have tried repairing (from control panel) and installation of all the above MVC frameworks, the .NET framework is 4.0

Do someone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mistake of my own, I was not selecting the correct .NET Framework, when I selected the .NET Framework 4, I got the MVC 4 as well as other project templates

[image: Correct .NET framework selection]
*answering so that others do not make this mistake.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ASP.NET MVC 4 for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1? http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30683